# Used Microsoft Word, header said compatibility mode. Saved changes are now lost

Tags: ms-word

I updated and old document using Microsoft Word. I saved the document several times and noticed the header said compatibility mode. Now when I open the file, the changes are gone. How do I recover the file with my changes? My company also started using network locations instead of drives. Don't know if this matters or not.

Tried opening the file, tried mapping the drive even thought we use network locations. Mapping failed anyway.

Comment: There is a superuser forum afaik that would be better suited for this. This site is for programming questions. I'm not sure compatibility mode is the cause of your issue. Afaik it just restricts the features that are available.